# opening and closing elementor-widget-container

Tags: plugins, css, javascript, templates

I want the following and hope you can help, I have created a container in Elementor and within this container I have added element  and direction row.
I want to the container to toggle with a button in the container, the toggle functionality is working.
But it opens the other container as well, how can I avoid that other containers are opening, only the clicked ones needs to open?

This is my code:

```
<div class="elementor-image-box-wrapper">
    <figure class="elementor-image-box-img">
      <img decoding="async" src="https://domain.xx/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/images/placeholder.png" title="" alt="" loading="lazy">
    </figure>
    <div class="elementor-image-box-content">
      <h3 class="elementor-image-box-title">Title</h3>
      <p class="elementor-image-box-description">
        Lorem ipsum.
        <span class="oo-dienst-panel-block">
         
          <span class="read-more-content"> Add here you panel content...</span>
          <span class="read-more-button" onclick="toggleReadMore(this)">Read more</span>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
elementor-widget-image-box .elementor-image-box-content {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .elementor-widget-image-box .read-more-content {
      display: none;
    }

    .elementor-widget-image-box .read-more-button {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #0073e6;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

...and my js.

```
 function toggleReadMore(button) {
    var content = button.parentElement.querySelector('.read-more-content');
    content.style.display = content.style.display === 'none' ? 'inline' : 'none';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a more specific selector query. There are several methods to achieve this, but I suggest that using the `sibling` property is the most straightforward way if your HTML structure remains constant.

```
var content = button.previousElementSibling; // Immediately prior to the button
```

However, choosing the `closest` method could be a reliable approach.

```
var content = button.closest('.read-more-content');
```